# Program works fine in compiler but not in jar (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, export

I Exported my program into a jar file but when I ran it, it seems as if the .properties file isn't found by the program. I made sure it was in the jar file & it worked fine prior to exporting it. I read something about using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` instead of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` but can't seem to understand how that would help. Any ideas? These are the two methods that use the file.

```
private void UpdateData() throws IOException{
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        in.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
        props.setProperty("prop1", prop1TextArea.getText().toString());
        props.setProperty("prop2", prop2TextArea.getText().toString());
        props.setProperty("prop3", prop3TextArea.getText().toString());
        props.store(out, null);
        out.close();

}

    private void setText() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        in.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
        prop1TextArea.setText(props.getProperty("prop1"));
        prop2TextArea.setText(props.getProperty("prop2"));
        prop3TextArea.setText(props.getProperty("prop3"));
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information if you want to enable people to help you. As a start post the error message and the code that you suspect that causes the error...

Comment: If you use FileInputStream, don't pack the properties file into the JAR file, rather place the properties file into the execution path (normally the same as the JAR, or possible that BAT file used to start it!?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access resources in your `.jar` file you have to access them as resources not as files.

The `.properties` are not in the filesystem anymore and therefore you cannot access them via `FileInputStream`.

If you want to save them afterwards you have to create new `.properties` on the first start of your program. So you have to check first if the file exists (e.g. via `File.exists()`) and either work without the properties from the file or create a new file and use this then.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now this isn't as important, but the file was created on my desktop. If I were to give this program to someone, is there a way the file could be created in a folder or something? Just to make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: You can provide any path you want. Please ask a new question to ask how you can specify a path, e.g. the users home path.